# Do I need to put ObjectAnimator inside an AsyncTask?

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask

I'm working on a little app that uses ObjectAnimator.
I need to get the animation progress using getAnimatorCurrentTime inside an AnimatorUpdateListener. I was wondering, do I need to put all my ObjectAnimator code inside an AsyncTask? or is ok to put it in the main thread? Its the first app that I want to publish and I want my app to be optimized. I don't want to have a crap*y app that crashes every 2 second.

Comment: All work with UI must be run in main thread

Comment: Don't worry. You don't need to involve the AsyncTask when using ObjectAnimator.  Use the ObjectAnimator correctly and you won't have any problem.  Go check out some of the animation sample apps in the SDK.